# Ruby unit test :run a test class from the main class

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

In Ruby unit testing can I run a test class from another class

for exa

```
class Foo < Test::Unit:: TestCase

test_abc()
test_bnd()
```

Now i want to run this above test suite from my main class

so how could i do it I tried using `runner` 
but dono wat should be argument to the `run` method

```
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(FOO)
```

,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

That is correct(refer http://www.ensta.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/classes/Test/Unit.html)

```
require 'test/unit/ui/console/testrunner'
Test::Unit::UI::Console::TestRunner.run(TC_MyTest)
```